# command not found when runng bash script as user apache

Tags: linux, apache, bash

I am trying to run a bash script as user apache. and it throws up the following

```
[apache@denison public]$ ll
total 32
drwxr-xr-x 2 apache apache 4096 Jul 17 08:14 css
-rw-r--r-- 1 apache apache 4820 Jul 17 10:04 h3111142_58_2012-07-17_16-03-58.php
-rwxrwxrwx 1 apache apache   95 Jul 17 10:04 h31111.bash
drwxr-xr-x 2 apache apache 4096 Jul 17 08:14 images
-rw-r--r-- 1 apache apache  754 Jul 17 08:13 index.php
drwxr-xr-x 2 apache apache 4096 Jul 17 08:14 javascript
drwxr-xr-x 5 apache apache 4096 Jul 17 08:14 jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom
[apache@denison public]$ bash h31111.bash
: command not found :
```

contents of the file are:

```
#!/bin/bash

/usr/bin/php /opt/eposdatatransfer/public/h3111142_58_2012-07-17_16-03-58.php
```

php script runs fine below are the results

```
[apache@denison public]$ /bin/bash h31111.bash
: command not found:
[apache@denison public]$ chmod +x h31111.bash
[apache@denison public]$ ./h31111.bash
./h31111.bash: Command not found.
[apache@denison public]$ php h3111142_58_2012-07-17_16-03-58.php
```

creation of file:

```
$batchFile = $this->session->username . "_" . $index . "_" . $date . ".sh";
            $handle = fopen($batchFile, 'w');
            $data = "#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/php /opt/eposdatatransfer/public/$file 
";
            /*
rm -rf /opt/eposdatatransfer/public/$file
rm -rf /opt/eposdatatransfer/public/$batchFile*";*/
            fwrite($handle, $data);
            fclose($handle);
```

batchfile is the bash script and file is the php file. These get craeted automatically based on user input in webapp. my webapp runs on linux.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you uploaded the script from a windows machine, and didn't strip the carriage returns from the end of the lines.  This causes the #! mechanism (the first line of most scripts) to fail, because it searches for #!/some/interpreter^M, which rarely exists.

You can probably strip the carriage returns, if you have them, using fromdos or:

```
tr -d '\015' < /path/to/script > /tmp/script; chmod 755 /tmp/script; mv /tmp/script /path/to/script
```

Comment: im not creating them in windows. it is being creating by my web app running on linux. `$batchFile = $this->session->username . "_" . $index . "_" . $date . ".sh";
      $handle = fopen($batchFile, 'w');
      $data = "#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/php /opt/eposdatatransfer/public/$file 
";
      /*
rm -rf /opt/eposdatatransfer/public/$file
rm -rf /opt/eposdatatransfer/public/$batchFile*";*/
      fwrite($handle, $data);
      fclose($handle);`

Answer (score 1):

What happens if you try to run your script with

```
 $ /bin/bash h31111.bash
```

Try this (assuming your script file is named "h31111.bash"):

```
 $ chmod +x h31111.bash
```

then to run it

```
 $ ./h31111.bash
```

Also are you sure you have the right path for your `php` command? What does `which php` report?

--

As @jordanm correctly suggests based on the output of the `file` command I suggested you run, you need to run the `dos2unix` command on your file. If you don't have that installed this `tr -d '\r'` will also work. I.e.,

```
 $ tr -d '\r' h31111.bash > tmp.bash
 $ mv tmp.bash h31111.bash
```

and you should be all set.

Under some versions of Ubuntu these utilities (e.g., dos2unix) don't come installed, for information on this see [this page](http://www.virtualhelp.me/linux/164-dos2unix-missing-ubuntu-1004).

Comment: see above I have updated same problem. it runs the bash script which runs the php script. however if i run it through webserver or batch queue it does not work at all

Comment: `[apache@denison public]$ ls -l /bin/bash
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 801528 May 13  2011 /bin/bash
[apache@denison public]$ which bash
/bin/bash
`

Comment: `[apache@denison public]$ which php
/usr/bin/php
[apache@denison public]$ 
`

Comment: @sharif Ok, one more command `file h31111.bash` gives what output?

Comment: `/usr/bin/php
[apache@denison public]$ file h31111.bash
h31111.bash: Bourne-Again shell script text executable
`

Comment: What does `cat -vet h31111.bash` show - are there some odd/unexpected characters in the file? I wonder if there's something hiding on that otherwise blank line... Or maybe line ending issues...

Comment: `[apache@denison public]$ cat -vet h31111.bash
#!/bin/bash^M$
set -x^M$
set -v^M$
/usr/bin/php /opt/eposdatatransfer/public/h3111142_58_2012-07-17_16-03-58.php ^M$
`

Comment: @jordanm You are right, I didn't get back to this question until now to see the output of the `file` command I had suggested. Since I don't have dos2unix installed on my system I suggested `tr -d '\r'` (but I also mentioned your suggestion - thanks)

Answer (score 0):

Since you're not sure where it's failing, let's try to find out.

First, can you execute the program?

```
./h31111.bash
```

That should be equivalent to invoking it with:

```
/bin/bash h31111.bash
```

If the above gives you the same error message than it's likely a problem with the script contents. To figure out where something's gone awry in a bash script, you can use `set -x` and  `set -v`.

`set -x` will show you expansions
`set -v` will show you the lines before their read

So, you'd change your script contents to something like the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x
set -v
/usr/bin/php /opt/eposdatatransfer/public/h3111142_58_2012-07-17_16-03-58.php
```

Another possibility, which you probably only learn by experience, is that the file is in MSDOS mode (i.e., has CR LF's instead of just LFs).  This often happens if you're still using FTP (as opposed to SFTP) and in ASCII mode. You may be able to set your transfer mode to binary and have everything work successfully. If not, you have a few options. **Any** of the following lines should work:

```
dos2unix /path/to/your/file
sed -i 's/\r//g' /path/to/your/file
tr -d '\r' < /path/to/your/file > /path/to/temp/file && mv /path/to/temp/file /path/to/your/file
```

In Vim, you could do `:set ff=unix` and save the file to change the format as well.

Let's take a look at what you have in PHP:

```
$handle = fopen($batchFile, 'w');
$data = "#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/php /opt/eposdatatransfer/public/$file 
";
```

Since you have a multi-line string, the CR LF characters that are embedded will depend on whether your PHP file is in Windows or Unix format. You could switch that file to Windows format and you'd be fine. But that seems easy to break in the future, so I'd go with something a little less volatile:

```
$handle = fopen($batchFile, 'w');
fwrite($handle, "#!/bin/bash\n");
fwrite($handle, "/usr/bin/php /opt/eposdatatransfer/public/$file\n");
fclose($handle);
```

Comment: `[apache@denison public]$ /bin/bash h31111.bash 
: invalid optione 2: set: -
set: usage: set [--abefhkmnptuvxBCHP] [-o option] [arg ...]
: invalid optione 3: set: -
set: usage: set [--abefhkmnptuvxBCHP] [-o option] [arg ...]
`

Comment: This script gets created in my web app which works perfectly fine in a different server. on the production server it does not and i get the errors as i have mentioned

Comment: If you're using FTP in ASCII mode, that'll cause the carriage return characters to be added. Post edited to give further options.

Comment: How would i do this in php? my webapp is creating this file automatically depending on variables etc.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me the problem is your $PATH.  Some users on the system will have **.** (the current directory) in their $PATH and others will not.  If typing ./h31111.bash works, then that's your problem.  You can either specify the file with a relative or absolute path, or you can add . to the $PATH of that user **but never do that for root**.

Comment: In UNIX/Linux, the variable $PATH holds the list of directories to look for executable files in, just like %PATH% in Windows.  If you type in the name of an executable file (either binary or script) without a path name, it will look in all of those places for it.  And that variable can (and usually is) set differently for different users.  If you type in the name of an executable file without a path that's not in one of those places, the shell can't find it, even if it's in the current directory (.), if . is not in $PATH.  For safety reasons many users don't have that in $PATH.